# How to get rid of duplicate rows from a SQL join due to bad table design?

Tags: sql, ms-access

I'm adding 6 columns to my main table with a left join, but the right table has duplicates in the primary key column because it wasn't designed properly. I can't fix that so I have to work with I've got. I'm doing this in MS Access so I don't have access to things like Group By Partition.

Table for the join:

| KeyID | PA | QL |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1111 | X |  |
| 1111 |  | X |

I want my final table to look like this:

| KeyID | PA | QL |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1111 | X | X |

How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use two subqueries:

```sql
SELECT 
    KeyID, 
    (Select PA 
    From YourTable As T 
    Where T.KeyID = YourTable.KeyID And PA Is Not Null) AS PA, 
    (Select QL 
    From YourTable As T 
    Where T.KeyID = YourTable.KeyID And QL Is Not Null) AS QL
FROM 
    YourTable
GROUP BY 
    KeyID;
```

Comment: This worked, thanks! The only downside is that Access doesn't handle sub queries very well and it takes a bit to load, but thankfully the dataset in question is rather small. I'll have to figure out a different solution though if the data gets larger.

Comment: Great! Then please mark as answered.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure I understand the problem, but you can apply an aggregate function such as MAX to get rid of nulls:

```
SELECT t1.KeyID, MAX(t2.PA) AS PA, MAX(t2.QL) AS QL
FROM t1
LEFT JOIN t2
    ON t1.KeyID = t2.KeyID
GROUP  BY t1.KeyID;
```

Answer (score 0):

My idea isn't very scalable, because you'd have to make a new query for every column that you have this issue with, but here is how I would do it.

Make 3 queries:

1. [Distinct KeyID] only
2. main table WHERE PA IS NOT NULL
3. main table WHERE QL IS NOT NULL

Now the 4th query,

```
SELECT query1.KeyID, query2.PA, query3.QL
FROM query1
LEFT OUTER JOIN query2 ON query1.KeyID = query2.KeyID
LEFT OUTER JOIN query3 ON query1.KeyID = query3.KeyID
```

Comment: MS-Access doesn't support `OUTER JOIN`. Only `LEFT`, `RIGHT` & `INNER` are support to ms-access.